# Can't access photos taken within app on Google Glass

Tags: android, android-camera, google-glass, imgur

I'm on a roll here with being confused with Google Glass development! My app is currently taking photos using the built-in camera functionality and the sample code on the GDK site (https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/camera). When I take a photo, it looks like a picture is being taken, but then when I try to upload it to an imgur server (using their API), I get a FileNotFound Exception. Also when I try using Android Studio's File Explorer, I can't seem to find any images in the filepath it should be in. It seems like the file is not being created, or I'm accessing the wrong path somehow. What could I be doing wrong?

Code for using the camera:

```
    public void startRecog(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.i(TAG,"Got to onActivity");
        Log.i(TAG,"Request code: " + requestCode + ", Result code: " + resultCode + ", what it wants: " + RESULT_OK);
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.i(TAG,"Got inside the IF");
            String picturePath = data.getStringExtra(Intents.EXTRA_THUMBNAIL_FILE_PATH);
          //  String picturePath = data.getStringExtra(Intents.EXTRA_PICTURE_FILE_PATH);

            Log.i(TAG,"The real path: " + picturePath);
            processPictureWhenReady(picturePath);
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private void processPictureWhenReady(final String picturePath) {
        final File pictureFile = new File(picturePath);

        if (pictureFile.exists()) {
            // The picture is ready; process it.
            Log.i(TAG,"Got in from the picture processing");
            new ImgurUploadTask(Uri.parse(picturePath), this).execute();
        } else {
            // The file does not exist yet. Before starting the file observer, you
            // can update your UI to let the user know that the application is
            // waiting for the picture (for example, by displaying the thumbnail
            // image and a progress indicator).

            final File parentDirectory = pictureFile.getParentFile();
            FileObserver observer = new FileObserver(parentDirectory.getPath(),
                    FileObserver.CLOSE_WRITE | FileObserver.MOVED_TO) {
                // Protect against additional pending events after CLOSE_WRITE
                // or MOVED_TO is handled.
                private boolean isFileWritten;

                @Override
                public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
                    if (!isFileWritten) {
                        // For safety, make sure that the file that was created in
                        // the directory is actually the one that we're expecting.
                        File affectedFile = new File(parentDirectory, path);
                        isFileWritten = affectedFile.equals(pictureFile);

                        if (isFileWritten) {
                            stopWatching();

                            // Now that the file is ready, recursively call
                            // processPictureWhenReady again (on the UI thread).
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    processPictureWhenReady(picturePath);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            observer.startWatching();
        }
    }
```

The errors I am getting:

```
11-01 14:34:43.281  10449-10449/com.example.cerveau.recognizeplaces I/RecogPlaces﹕ Got to onActivity
11-01 14:34:43.281  10449-10449/com.example.cerveau.recognizeplaces I/RecogPlaces﹕ Request code: 100, Result code: -1, what it wants: -1
11-01 14:34:43.281  10449-10449/com.example.cerveau.recognizeplaces I/RecogPlaces﹕ Got inside the IF
11-01 14:34:43.281  10449-10449/com.example.cerveau.recognizeplaces I/RecogPlaces﹕ The real path: /storage/emulated/0/storage/emulated/0/thumbnail_cache/t_thumb_20141101_143439_397.jpg
11-01 14:34:43.281  10449-10449/com.example.cerveau.recognizeplaces I/RecogPlaces﹕ Got in from the picture processing
11-01 14:34:43.288  10449-10704/com.example.cerveau.recognizeplaces E/ImgurUploadTask﹕ could not open InputStream
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: /storage/emulated/0/thumbnail_cache/t_thumb_20141101_143439_397.jpg
            at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1049)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:904)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:629)
            at com.example.cerveau.recognizeplaces.ImgurUploadTask.doInBackground(ImgurUploadTask.java:32)
            at com.example.cerveau.recognizeplaces.ImgurUploadTask.doInBackground(ImgurUploadTask.java:16)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:302)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:240)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

And yes, I think I have the right permissions set in my AndroidManifest...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.glass.permission.DEVELOPMENT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Thanks guys! I keep butting my head into problems every step of the way with developing for Glass and it's frustrating me to no end. I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

```
new ImgurUploadTask(Uri.parse(picturePath)
```

This is your problem. You can't use Uri.parse on a storage path (like "/storage/emulated/0/thumbnail_cache...") because it is not qualified.

Create the Uri like this:

```
Uri.fromFile(pictureFile)
```

This will output a valid Uri beginning with "file://".